# How to make a artboard / design space for a billboard c. 20m x 3m in Illustrator / Indesign

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I need to design graphics for a billboard in illustrator or indesign.

The billboard is also not square / rectangular, but rather custom polygon shape. The overall dimensions are around 20m x 3m.

I have a survey of the custom polygon shape in Vectorworks (CAD software) as a vector object that i can copy and paste to into Adobe Illustrator / InDesign.

But it always imports the shape at the wrong size.

I also tried to setup a custom document size in InDesign and re-draw the shape, but this did not work either as the largest document size InDesign seemed to allow was around 5m wide.

Any idea how i can get this large custom shape into Adobe Illustrator / InDesign ?

Ive thought of a work around where i just work in Illustrator / InDesign at 1:10th scale, but this seems like an un-nessacery work around, as lots of other people must have designed billboards before and I wondered how they do it ?

The billboard graphics itself are just going to be text and vector shapes, no images / gradients. I would like to work at 1:1 scale just so i can get an idea of the text / graphics size as im developing them.

Comment: While not always 1:10, designing at scale for things like billboards is a common practice. If you speak to your vendor about how to set-up the file, they'll probably recommend some amount of scale. Not only does it mean smaller files for you to work with (not just dimension but also bytes), but also a file that doesn't take hours for the printer to rip into their system.

Comment: Also, designing "at size" so you can get a better feel for how everything is working together/text sizing doesn't really make sense in this case unless you have a monitor that's 20 x 3 meters - you're still going to be zooming out to some scale in order to preview the whole document on screen anyway.

Comment: (a monitor of 20x3m...) This last comment is pure wisdom.

Comment: Could use a projector for a monitor.. need a heck of a large room though :)

Answer (score 2):

> at 1:10th scale, but this seems like an unnecessary workaround

No, it is not unnecessary, you need to do it because you can not make documents that big.

> lots of other people must have designed billboards before and I wondered how they do it?

Making them at scale.

> I can get an idea of the text/graphics size as I'm developing them.

Use a 1:10 scale, if the program says 10 cm you know its 1 m.

Almost everything big needs to be planed at a scale. A house, a stadium, a road, a big billboard.